# Trouble finding the best linear predictor

Tags: statistics

How can we find the best linear predictor of $\{X_t\}$ that is 
$X_t+b_1X_{t-1}+・・・b_pX_{t-p}=u_t,\{u_t\}～i.i.d(0,σ^2)$
and $1+b_1z+・・・+b_pz^p≠0,|Z|≦0$